# Android: Writing to separate files?

Tags: android, file, android-handler

Within my current android application I am reading in data from game sessions, using a handler, that is then written to file.

Currently all data is written to the one file. I.e. every separate session's data is into the one file. I want to change this so that each time a new game is completed it's data is entered into its own separate unique file.

How can I do so?

**Current handler:**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // msg.what determines the type of each message
            switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_EEG_POWER:

                eegPower = (TGEegPower) msg.obj;
                //trace code
                Log.d("LSD", "highAlpha: " + eegPower.highAlpha);
                Log.d("LSD", "lowAlpha: " + eegPower.lowAlpha);
                Log.d("LSD", "highBeta: " + eegPower.highBeta);
                Log.d("LSD", "lowBeta: " + eegPower.lowBeta);
                Log.d("LSD", "lowGamma: " + eegPower.lowGamma);
                Log.d("LSD", "midGamma: " + eegPower.midGamma);
                Log.d("LSD", "delta: " + eegPower.delta);
                Log.d("LSD", "theta: " + eegPower.theta);

                //adding all the EEGpowers to an arraylist to help add them to file
                ArrayList<String> EEGPowers= new ArrayList<String>();

                EEGPowers.add("highAlpha: " + eegPower.highAlpha);
                EEGPowers.add("lowAlpha: " + eegPower.lowAlpha);
                EEGPowers.add("highBeta: " + eegPower.highBeta);
                EEGPowers.add("lowBeta: " + eegPower.lowBeta);
                EEGPowers.add("lowGamma: " + eegPower.lowGamma);
                EEGPowers.add("midGamma: " + eegPower.midGamma);
                EEGPowers.add("delta: " + eegPower.delta);
                EEGPowers.add("theta: " + eegPower.theta);



                //setting up the array of maxlength etc
                spaces[0] = "";
                for(int i=1; i<maxWordLength ;i++){
                    spaces[i] = spaces[i-1]+" ";
                }

                int seconds=0;

                //creating header in txt file
                writeToFileEEGPower(order("Seconds")+order("highAlpha")+order("lowAlpha")+order("highBeta")+order("LowBeta")+
                        order("lowGamma")+order("midGamma")+order("Delta")+order("Theta")+ "\n");

                //creating the string to be written to file
                String line = order(seconds+"")+order(eegPower.highAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.lowAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.highBeta+"")+
                        order(eegPower.lowBeta+"")+order(eegPower.midGamma+"")+order(eegPower.delta+"")+order(eegPower.theta+"")+ "\n";

                //write the string to file
                writeToFileEEGPower(line);
```

**Current writetofile method:**

```
public void writeToFileEEGPower(String data){

            //creating time for the file 
            Time t= new Time();
            int timeFileSecond= t.second;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "MathsGame" + timeFileSecond + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;

            //creating the file where the contents will be written to
            File file= new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");

            FileOutputStream os;

            try{

                boolean append= true;

                os= new FileOutputStream(file, append);

                String writeMe =data + "\n";

                os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

                os.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

EDIT:

```
//CURRENTLY CREATES A FILE BASED ON MINUTE, NEED TO CHANGE
            Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;


            //creating file name
            String fileName= timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;

            //creating the file where the contents will be written to
            File file= new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");
```

Comment: You already seem to be creating a new file for each call to writeToFileEEGPower(), unless you call it more than once in a second.

Comment: No, currently the values from all sessions are in the one file?

Answer (score 1):

```
Time t= new Time();
```

Is documented to initialize the Time object to January 1st, 1970, so all your files will be the same.

To do what you appear to by trying to, set the object to now:

```
Time t= new Time();
t.setToNow();
timeFileSecond= t.second;
//etc
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this implementation but it is creating a file every second. I do not want this. I want a file for each game session that contains all data and with a unique name?

Comment: You are going to have to decide what constitutes a "session" then - it's a concept foreign to android, so you will have to define it for yourself.  Then you can determine the filename once per session, keep it with your other session data, and pass it as an argument to your storing method.

Comment: Could you just use a random number as the filename, as long as it is unique? Please see my edit, I am trying to use the minute but it is not working properly as one session may stretch over 2 mins!